# Problem with WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv()

Tags: vba, worksheet-function, inverse

I am trying to make a modelisation of Monte-Carlo for 5000 trials. 
I seem to have a weird problem with

`g = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(Rnd())`

During the functioning of the loop (of the 5000 trials), at first it is working but then an error message occurs:

`Run-time error "1004": 
Method 'Norm_S_Inv' of object 'WorksheetFunction' failed`

I have checked on many VBA sites and I don't seem to find a solution. 
I also tested with

- `Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(Rnd())`
- with `WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(Rnd())`
- with `WorksheetFunction.Norm.S.Inv`
- with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm.S.Inv(Rnd())`
- with `WorksheetFunction.NormSInv`

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when your `Rnd()` returns a value of `0` or `1`, which is of course an acceptable value for the `Rnd()` function but it is not as an input of the `Norm_S_Inv()`.

I can reproduce that easily on my computer (my Excel is in Italian, actually I get the `1004` code but the text on my side rather says "Cannot find property Norm_S_Inv for the class WorksheetFunction):

```
g = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(0.14)
Debug.Print g
>>> -1.08031934081496

g = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(0) 'or g = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(1)
>>>
```

[image]

In order to avoid that, make sure you don't get `0` or `1` as inputs of your function:

```
myRand = Rnd()
Do Until (myRand <> 0 And myRand <> 1)
    myRand = Rnd()
Loop
g = WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Inv(myRand)
```

**Personal note:** this seems a pretty bad error handling done for this function, the error message is not at all clear and I understand your frustration in finding the root cause.